# Move Options Up / Down List-box JavaScript / ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi I'm trying to learn javascript and I'm messing around with this [example](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/selectbox/source.html) I found:

```
function moveOptionUp(obj) {
if (!hasOptions(obj)) { return; }
    for (i = 0; i < obj.options.length; i++) {
       if (obj.options[i].selected) {
       if (i != 0 && !obj.options[i - 1].selected) {
           swapOptions(obj, i, i - 1);
           obj.options[i - 1].selected = true;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

I have a list box

```
<input type="button" value="Up" onclick="moveOptionUp(this.form['_lb2'])" />
<asp:ListBox ID="_lb2" name="_lb2" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="170px"/>
```

However I can't get it to work ... The example uses a html select box.  I think the problem is with passing in the control as a parameter.  What is the correct way to do this using asp controls.

Ohh BTW .. List box items are added dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move an option up one, insert it as the previous sibling of the previous option (provided it isn't the top one already):

```
function moveUp(sel) {
  var idx = sel.selectedIndex;
  var opt;

  // Only move up if not first
  if (idx > 0) {
    opt = sel.options[idx];
    sel.insertBefore(opt, sel.options[--idx]);
  }
}
```

Changed the test to check that `idx > 0` since if no option is selected the *selectedIndex* will be -1. That may happen if there is no defalut selected option and the form is reset.

#### Edit

Sample HTML:

```
<form action="">
  <select id="_lb2" name="_lb2">
    <option>0
    <option>1
    <option>2
    <option>3
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Move Up" onclick="
    moveUp(this.form['_lb2']);
  ">
</form>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the alternative (it looks cleaner) ... however it still doesn't work with the method call I'm using ... Can you tell me if onclick="moveUp(this.form['_lb2'])" would be the correct way to call that function with an ASP list box .. ?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine provided the button and select are in the same form.

Comment: I wish I could mark these both as answers because I can only get your function to work with mdmullinax method call lol ... Thank you All ...Move Down is insertafter with ++idx ?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the insertAfter   ........ whats wrong              if (idx) {
                    opt = sel.options[idx];
                    sel.insertAfter(opt, sel.options[++idx]);

Comment: There is no insertAfter method. To move an option down, make sure idx < options.length - 1, then do `sel.insertBefore(opt, sel.options[idx+1].nextSibling)`. If there is no nextSibling, it will be inserted at the end. Or you could just do `sel.options[++idx] = opt;`

Answer (score 1):

> I think the problem is with passing in the control as a parameter

Indeed...

change

```
onclick="moveOptionUp(this.form['_lb2'])"
```

to

```
onclick="moveOptionUp(document.getElementById('_lb2'))"
```

btw, (and you may already know this) an id of `_lb2` is not considered [valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)